# Is it possible to mix val and var when destructuring in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that returns `Pair<Int, Int>`. In the calling function, I want to overwrite one of those values on a condition, but keep the other constant.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about to more easily see what I'm asking for.

```kotlin
fun doThing(): Pair<Int, Int> {
   return Pair(3, 5)
}

fun main() {
   // I want thing1 to be a val, but thing2 to be a var
   val (thing1, thing2) = doThing()
}
```

From my testing around it doesn't seem possible, but I also have found nothing in searching documentation and other Stackoverflow posts.

Comment: The [grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/syntax-and-grammar.html#syntax-grammar) clearly prohibits a syntax such as `(val thing1, var thing2) = expression`. I don't know whether that's enough to convince you though.

Comment: That's enough to convince me. I was more wondering as someone new to the language if there was a different syntax altogether that allows one to do such a thing, since having a constant value be mutable goes against basic programming principles.